# Can custom TensorFlow user_ops be served through TensorFlow Serving

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I have created  custom TensorFlow operators in C++ similar to the examples in tensorflow/user/ops/ and they are working fine when used in TensorFlow sessions.

When saving a SavedModel using the operator, the resulting saved_model does contain the operators (at least a cursory inspection of a text protocol buffer of such a model shows that). Trying to serve this with a tensorflow_model_server of course fails at first, since the operator is unknown.

So I proceeded to extend the tensorflow_model_server with an option to specify the user_ops libraries to be loaded beforehand. The relevant code snippet inserted into "main.cc" of the tensorflow_model_server is:

```
if (librarypath.size() > 0) {
    // Load the library.
    TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
    TF_LoadLibrary(librarypath.c_str(), status);
    if (!TF_GetCode(status) == TF_OK) {
        string status_msg(TF_Message(status));
        std::cout << "Problem loading user_op library " <<  librarypath << ": " << TF_Message(status);
   return -1;    }
   TF_DeleteStatus(status);
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not quite work as expected, I get

```
Problem loading user_op library /usr/lib64/multipolygon_op.so: /usr/lib64   /multipolygon_op.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN10tensorflow8OpKernelE
```

This somehow refers to _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so symbols. Do I need to build the user op library differently or am I just out of luck ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after a trying out a number of different venues the answer turns out to be relatively simple:

The tensorflow_model_server is being linked in such a way that is does not provide its own symbols to newly loaded shared libraries. Thus adding "-rdynamic" to the linker options to change that makes everything fall into place:

```
     bazel build --linkopt=-rdynamic //tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server
```